# How to read exactly one byte in a binary file in C++

Tags: c++, file, binary, byte

I am trying to a read a single byte from a binary file, and I am getting inaccurate results.

This is the content of binary file:

`00000000  00 04 0A 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 74 00 00 00 00 61 69 6E 62 6F 77 00                                                                               ..........t....ainbow.`

The point is that I can read more than one byte, but I just can't read exactly one byte. If tried to read the third byte `0A` which is equal to `10`, instead it gives me a value of `32522` or in hexadecimal `7F0A`. What am I missing here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    fstream file("foo.daf", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);

    file.seekg(2);

    int x;

    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&x), 1);

    cout<<x<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems like you're going about it the wrong way.`unsigned char x; file >> x;`

Comment: `char c; if(file.get(c)) { /* read was successful, use c */ }`

Comment: @MorphingDragon: I doubt a formatted input function will achieve the desired results. In the case of this particular character, it definitely will not.

Comment: this seems to be a C++ question, so why is it also marked C?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`x` is not initialized, and you modify only one byte of it, so you have garbage for the other bytes.

Use directly the correct type should solve your issue (and avoid a cast).

```
char x;
```

Comment: ostream for a char display the character (which is `'\r'` in your case) not the number, you have to cast it to an integer to see its value.

Answer (score 7):

The following code is what you are looking for:

```
unsigned char x;
file.read(&x, 1);
cout << static_cast<int>(x) << endl;
```

It reads in a character and then converts it to an integer.

Comment: don't we have truncation here? how on earth a 4 byte integer fits into an unsigned char (1 byte)?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are reading an int.  An Int is more than one byte on almost all systems.  Int's are commonly 4 bytes, and sometimes 8 bytes.  You really want to read in a char as the previous comment says.

```
int main()
{

    fstream file("foo.daf", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);

    file.seekg(2);

    char x;

    file.read((&x), 1);

    cout<<x<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `file.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&x), 1);` <- this reads a `char` (which happens to overlap an `int` for bad reasons), not an `int`.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it is also not a fully correct solution. `char` equals `byte` according to C++ specification, but specification's `byte` does not 100% mean 8 `bits`. So if you want to read 8 bit bytes, you'd need to use fixed sized 8 bit type and pack `chars` to it. Which is =(

Comment: I'm not sure that `int8_t` can be supported on systems which have 16 bit `char` though.